# acc, loss, val_acc and val_loss are same in every epoch

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm using convolution neural network to train my model. When i am training my model than the value of accuracy, loss , val_acc and val_loss are same i searched about it on github but i didn't get the solution of my problem.
Help me to solve this problem.

I am using the concept of siamese netwrok where i defined two architecture and i have two dataset and 48000 images in both dataset these images i have for training and for validation i have 6000 images. My goal is to concatenate the features of both the architecture 
here is my code

```
def VGG_16(weights_path=None,include_top=False):
    visible = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
    zero11 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(visible)
    conv11 = Conv2D(64,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero11)
    zero12 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv11)
    conv12 = Conv2D(64,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero12)
    pool11 = MaxPooling2D((2,2,),strides=(2,2,))(conv12)


    zero13 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(pool11)
    conv13 = Conv2D(128,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero13)
    zero14 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv13)
    conv14 = Conv2D(128,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero14)
    pool12 = MaxPooling2D((2,2,),strides=(2,2,))(conv14)



    zero15 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(pool12)
    conv15 = Conv2D(256,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero15)
    zero16 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv15)
    conv16 = Conv2D(256,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero16)
    pool13 = MaxPooling2D((2,2,),strides=(2,2,))(conv16)


    zero17 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(pool13)
    conv17 = Conv2D(512,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero17)
    zero18 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv17)
    conv18 = Conv2D(512,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero18)
    pool14 = MaxPooling2D((2,2,),strides=(2,2,))(conv18)


    zero19 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(pool14)
    conv19 = Conv2D(512,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero19)
    zero20 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv19)
    conv20 = Conv2D(512,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero20)
    pool15 = MaxPooling2D((2,2,),strides=(2,2,))(conv20)


    flat = Flatten()(pool15)

    visible1=Input(shape=(224,224,3))
    zero21 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(visible)
    conv21 = Conv2D(64,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero21)
    zero22 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv21)
    conv22 = Conv2D(64,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero22)
    pool21 = MaxPooling2D((2,2,),strides=(2,2,))(conv22)


    zero23 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(pool21)
    conv23 = Conv2D(128,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero23)
    zero24 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv23)
    conv24 = Conv2D(128,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero24)
    pool22 = MaxPooling2D((2,2,),strides=(2,2,))(conv24)



    zero25 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(pool22)
    conv25 = Conv2D(256,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero25)
    zero26 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv25)
    conv26 = Conv2D(256,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero26)
    pool23 = MaxPooling2D((2,2,),strides=(2,2,))(conv26)


    zero27 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(pool23)
    conv27 = Conv2D(512,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero27)
    zero28 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv27)
    conv28 = Conv2D(512,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero28)
    pool24 = MaxPooling2D((2,2,),strides=(2,2,))(conv28)


    zero29 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(pool24)
    conv29 = Conv2D(512,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero29)
    zero30 = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(conv29)
    conv30 = Conv2D(512,kernel_size=4,activation='relu')(zero30)
    pool25 = MaxPooling2D((2,2,),strides=(2,2,))(conv30) 


    flat1 = Flatten()(pool25)

    merge = concatenate([flat,flat1])
    dropout=Dropout(0.5)(merge)
    hidden = Dense(512,activation='relu')(dropout)
    dropout1= Dropout(0.5)(hidden)
    hidden1= Dense(512,activation='relu')(dropout1)


    output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(hidden1)

    model = Model(inputs=[visible,visible1], outputs=output)

    return model
model = VGG_16()
model.summary()

train='/home/project_deepak/deepak/siamese_network/Dataset/CPRI/train/'
train1='/home/project_deepak/deepak/siamese_network/Dataset/DATA_PV/data_pv/Train/'
val='/home/project_deepak/deepak/siamese_network/Dataset/CPRI/Validation/'
val1='/home/project_deepak/deepak/siamese_network/Dataset/DATA_PV/data_pv/Validation_data_PV/'

train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                       shear_range = 0.2, 
                                       zoom_range = 0.2,
                                       rotation_range=5.,
                                       horizontal_flip = True)

val_imgen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)


def generate_generator_multiple(generator,dir1, dir2, batch_size, img_height,img_width):
    genX1 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir1,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=7)

    genX2 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir2,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=7)
    while True:
            X1i = genX1.next()
            X2i = genX2.next()
           # print(len(X1i[0]), len(X2i[0]))
           # x = X1i[0]
           # y = X2i[0]
           # print(x.shape, y.shape)
#             print(X1i,X2i.shape)
            yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1]  #Yield both images and their mutual label


train_generator=generate_generator_multiple(generator=train_datagen,
                                           dir1=train,
                                           dir2=train1,
                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                           img_height=img_height,
                                           img_width=img_height)       


val_generator=generate_generator_multiple(val_imgen,
                                          dir1=val,
                                          dir2=val1,
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          img_height=img_height,
                                          img_width=img_height)   

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])
history=model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                        steps_per_epoch=1500,
                        epochs = epochs,
                        validation_data = val_generator,
                        validation_steps = 375,
                        #use_multiprocessing=True,
                        shuffle=True,
                        #show_accuracy = True,
                        #verbose=1)
>after run this code i am getting the same value in every epoch

Epoch 2/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1480s 987ms/step - loss: 10.7454 - acc: 0.3333 - val_loss: 10.7310 - val_acc: 0.3342
Epoch 3/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1479s 986ms/step - loss: 10.7454 - acc: 0.3333 - val_loss: 10.7310 - val_acc: 0.3342
Epoch 4/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1487s 991ms/step - loss: 10.7454 - acc: 0.3333 - val_loss: 10.7310 - val_acc: 0.3342
Epoch 5/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1469s 979ms/step - loss: 10.7454 - acc: 0.3333 - val_loss: 10.7310 - val_acc: 0.3342
Epoch 6/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1475s 983ms/step - loss: 10.7454 - acc: 0.3333 - val_loss: 10.7310 - val_acc: 0.3342
Epoch 7/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1482s 988ms/step - loss: 10.7454 - acc: 0.3333 - val_loss: 10.7310 - val_acc: 0.3342
Epoch 8/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1472s 981ms/step - loss: 10.7454 - acc: 0.3333 - val_loss: 10.7310 - val_acc: 0.3342
Epoch 9/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1468s 979ms/step - loss: 10.7454 - acc: 0.3333 - val_loss: 10.7310 - val_acc: 0.3342
Epoch 10/10
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1475s 983ms/step - loss: 10.7454 - acc: 0.3333 - val_loss: 10.7310 - val_acc: 0.3342
```

Comment: Can you add some context to your question? Model definition, training loop or your dataset information.

Comment: Without source code we cannot really help you.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thankyou for your response i added my source code